# Jasperstarter with different query in each report

Tags: php, mysqli, jasper-reports

i'm trying to figure out if this is possible using JasperStarter and PHP

I want to create invoices, and they offcourse need to differ depending on  what is being rented.

So for example i need to do an mySQL query like this:

```
SELECT thingBeingRented, price FROM invoices WHERE id LIKE $invoiceId
```

in my jrxml file before i compile and process it every time.

But is there anyway to pass the `$invoiceId` variable to the jrxml file?

I created the jrxml file using Jasper Studio.

Regards,
Johan

Comment: Of course! You can add parameters on Jasper Studio and use it in your report (in Jasper Studio, design mode, query editor) or directly on jrxml source code. Then you must append parameter on your report call, on your app. Parameter in your app must have same name as JasperStudio parameter. How are you calling report in your app?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help? https://github.com/cossou/JasperPHP ......